# how to insert concat command ,and the return result is like select

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDxTK.png)
what command do i have to write to have fullname columns = student_first_name + student_last_name.

i only know select concat command to filter, i want here that it will insert and display as select concat command.

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add a new column to table` and then use `update` command to ensure that you fill full name. Using `+` for `string` is ill-advised since it is mostly for `varchar` values not `nvarchar` values.
query in `SQL Server`

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD FullName VARCHAR(100); 

UPDATE yourtable
SET FullName=CONCAT(student_first_name ,student_last_name)
--SET FullName=student_first_name +student_last_name
```

query in `MYSQL`

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD COLUMN FullName VARCHAR(100) AFTER student_last_name;
UPDATE yourtable
SET FullName = CONCAT(student_first_name ,student_last_name)
--SET FullName=student_first_name +student_last_name
```

Comment: tks bro, my idea has been implemented, very appreciated

Comment: very glad to help